# pyodbc - ODBC Connection not working

Tags: python, pyodbc

I am new to Python and trying to use the library pyodbc to connect to an MS Access Database. I have a 32 bit database, and 32 bit drivers. I keep reading but am unable to understand what looks like a simple set of commands.

```
import pyodbc
DBfile = 'C:/Users/davisr/My Documents/TEMP/Comp_Model_Db_Testing.mdb'

conn = pyodbc.connect("Driver={Microsoft Access Driver(*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=DBfile")
```

The error that I received is as follows:
    C:\Python27\python.exe C:/Users/davisr/PycharmProjects/File_Names/ex1.py
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:/Users/davisr/PycharmProjects/File_Names/ex1.py", line 6, in 
    conn = pyodbc.connect("Driver={Microsoft Access Driver(*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=+DBfile")
    pyodbc.Error: ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found
List item and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')

Your help is appreciated. I am sure it is something simple.

Respectfully,

Robert Davis

Comment: Didn't use it for a long time, but I'm sure that the end of your connection string is wrong. Try to replace `"...DBD=DBFile"` with `"...DBQ=" + DBFile`

Comment: Tried the above and different error received:  File "C:/Users/davisr/PycharmProjects/File_Names/ex1.py", line 6
    conn = pyodbc.connect("Driver={Microsoft Access Driver(*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ="DBfile;)

Comment: I proposed you `...;DBQ=" + DBFile)` not `...;DBQ="DBfile;)`

Comment: @user2320821 The problems you are encountering boil down to string formatting. Take a look at the [examples](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-examples) and update your question with any specific questions you have.

Comment: I took the advice of beargle and Serge Ballesta and the following finally worked:    access_database_file = 'C:\\Users\\davisr\\My Documents\\TEMP\\Comp_Model_Db_Testing.mdb'

ODBC_CONN_STR = 'DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=%s;' %access_database_file

Comment: I was having similar issues, and the same error, not being able to connect to my driver.  For anyone seeing this now, and still not able to connect to your driver, this youtube video gives a great step by step tutorial for creating your own drive path...https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zw9P2wSnoIo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I took the advice of beargle and Serge Ballesta and the following finally worked:

```
access_database_file = 'C:\\Users\\davisr\\My Documents\\TEMP\\Comp_Model_Db_Testing.mdb'       
ODBC_CONN_STR = 'DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=%s;' %access_database_file–  user23208211 min ago
```

Thank you Serge and beargle